# Running Different Bash Commands Based on Java Version

Tags: java, bash, gcj

I'm trying to develop a bash build script for a Java project that will be run on Ubuntu and Fedora. Ubuntu uses the gcj compiler while Fedora uses IcedTea.

Both report their errors and warning in slightly different ways, and I want to ignore the warnings (I know, not generally a good idea, but some of the warnings are simply idiotic).

For gcj, I want to run:

```
javac *.java 2>&1 | grep -A 4 "error:"
```

but for IcedTea, I want to run:

```
javac *.java 2>&1 | grep -A 4 "error:\|errors\|.java:"
```

I'm still new to bash, so how would I write an if statement that would run one versus the other based upon the javac version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your java and javac binaries match, and that icedtea is the special case.

```
#!/bin/bash

ERROR="error:"

java -version 2>&1 | grep -i icedtea > /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
   ERROR="error:\|errors\|.java:"
fi

javac *.java 2>&1 | grep -A 4 $ERROR
```

On my system, icedtea and sun have the same output for "javac -version", but not for "java -version".

Comment: Vote up, nice version & simple (which i i like) and works well.

Answer (score 1):

```
    #!/bin/sh

    JAVAC_VERSION="`java -version 2>&1 /dev/null | awk '/IcedTea/ {print $4}' | sed -e 's/[\(0-9]//g'`"
    ICEDTEA="IcedTea"

    if [ ${JAVAC_VERSION} = ${ICEDTEA} ]; then
        javac *.java 2>&1 | grep -A 4 "error:\|errors\|.java:"
    else
        javac *.java 2>&1 | grep -A 4 "error:"
    fi

    exit 0
```

That should do it - if i understood your question correctly. How you get the version - im not quite sure of, but if my `javac -version` is incorrect just change it accordingly to your needs.

Comment: This is close, but I'm getting the error " [: javac: binary operator expected" on the second if statement.

Comment: Also, if I put a "echo $JAVAC_VERSION" right after the first line, it shows nothing.

Comment: Acknowledged, let me try it out.

Answer (score 1):

Writing Java build scripts in bash (or any other shell language) has a number of problems:

- scripts tend to be non-portable due to shell differences, different command locations, incompatible command options and so on ... even if you try to make the portable.
- scripts cannot cope with dependencies (or at least not easily)
- scripts cannot cope with recompiling only stuff that has changed

Instead, I suggest that you write a "build.xml" file and use the [Ant build tool](http://ant.apache.org).  Ant has the advantage of running on any build platform that runs Java, and of taking care of the vast majority of platform differences.  It is sort of like a better "Make" designed specifically for building Java.

Comment: -1 XML is somehow better than Makefile?  ant is a solution in search of a problem.  it exists simply because its author could not keep tabs where they belong and spaces where they're allowed in Makefiles.

Comment: It is not the use XML that makes Ant better than Make. (That is just a trivial syntactic difference IMO.) Rather it is Ant's execution model that makes all of the difference. The problem with Make is that it generates shell commands to be executed in a particular order, and those commands are typically non-portable. By contrast, with Ant you declare the tasks to be performed and let the Ant application (and plugin classes) figure out how to perform the tasks.